# Running all files in directory, what is go run ./cmd/*.go?

Tags: go

I am currently looking at this project ([Mattermost](https://github.com/mattermost/platform)) that has a certain line in the makefile that I'm confused about:

```
$(GO) run $(GOFLAGS) $(GO_LINKER_FLAGS) ./cmd/platform/*.go --disableconfigwatch &
```

What is the meaning of `./cmd/platform/*.go`? What specific files are executed? The program executes correctly when I type it in the terminal.

I am trying to enter the command line arguments in an IDE but I need a specific entry file.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org)
>
> [glob (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))
>
> > In computer programming, in particular in a Unix-like environment,
> >     glob patterns specify sets of filenames with wildcard characters. For
> >     example, the Unix command mv *.txt textfiles/ moves (mv) all files
> >     with names ending in .txt from the current directory to the directory
> >     textfiles. Here, * is a wildcard standing for "any string of
> >     characters" and *.txt is a glob pattern. The other common wildcard is
> >     the question mark (?), which stands for one character.

Clearly, `./cmd/platform/*.go`, starting in the current directory, looks in the `cmd/platform` directory for files matching the wildcard `*.go`.

The `ls ./cmd/platform/*.go` command will list the files on Linux.

So, the `go run ./cmd/platform/*.go` command compiles and runs these Go (`*.go`) source files. See [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) documentation: [Compile and run Go program](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program).